# mod_rewriting conflict with WP permalinks in htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need some help! I'm trying to rewrite this...

```
localhost/blog/?c=var  to->  localhost/blog/var
```

But seems there is some problem... **I get a 500** :( I also believe there is some conflict with the default rules of wordpress too. This is my entire htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) localhost/blog/?c=$1  [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but your rules look okay to me. Try using the IP address of your machine or `127.0.0.1` for localhost. Also, put a `"$"` after the closing parenthesis in your rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/.*$
RewriteRule /blog/?c=([^\&]*) $1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Since `RewriteBase` is defined, you shouldn't have to specify /blog/ again in the redirection part.

`RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase` needn't be repeated, not sure if repeating them causes problems.